# Visual Studio: multiple accounts for Azure and license

Tags: visual-studio, azure

For security reasons, we decided to create separate accounts for our Azure deployments.

Therefore, some users have an email account that holds Visual Studio license, and a separate account that has privileges on Azure subscriptions and no email address.

We use ADFS federation to log in to Azure. I tried to add the two accounts separately, but each time I validate authentication, it only displays my main (email) account.

I know that to log in to the Azure portal with my other account, I have to use Firefox.

Is there any way to do that with Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: You're doing "Right-click Publish"?

Comment: Hi,
I tried, with "right-click publish", I tried to add another account via "account setting" and via "server explorer"

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but in case others need it:

1. Sign into both accounts in Visual Studio (VS).  I recommend signing into the account with your VS license first.
2. Go to Tools > Options...
3. Search "Account Selection".  This should be under "Azure Service Authentication".
4. Select the account you would like to use for Azure Authentication.

---

If you're using the "DefaultAzureCredential" from the "Azure.Identity" Nuget package and still having issues, try signing into your Azure account in the CLI (az login).